# Batch command not executed from jenkins job

Tags: windows, jenkins

I created a job in jenkins, In that job remote server is windows and i wanted to execute a batch file in the job. at that time i face an issue like below. Iam unable to findout root cause.

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, 
this environment variable is needed to run this program. 
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Few batch files are executed and few are not executed in jenkins.present what i want to execute batch file it's working fine in remote server directly. But from jenkins it's not executed. when i tried to execute it shows above error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have one batch file which is selenium script. Iam able to run that script from with in the server, but when run that batch file from jenkins(connecting with nodes) getting above error.

Comment: "in local remote server" -- o_O Please re-read what you wrote, people here are smart but they can't somehow read info you don't provide or misrepresent. You can [edit] your question to transform it into something coherent.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajesh Gandhavarapu, I guess issue is that JAVA HOME is not set properly in your remote windows machine. You can try something below in your jenkins job.

1. Set JAVA_HOME variable
   Then use the following command to set the JAVA_HOME variable.

```
setx JAVA_HOME "path/to/your/java/jdk" /M
```

For example, we set

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92”
```

to JAVA_HOME

2. Ensure your java home is set properly using echo command

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Comment: @apan-hegde, 1.8.0_92 is significantly out of date. Latest is 331 as of today. You should update.

Comment: @IanW Thanks for pointing out. I was just giving example, its better to use latest versions of jdk

Comment: first of all thanks for reply, in my remote windows server java home is working fine.

Comment: @TapanHegde  I had a doubt, where can i setup environment varible in jenkins or windows server?  --> if it can setup in windows it's working fine. If incase it setup in jenkins where can i setup JAVA_HOME

Comment: @Rajesh Gandhavarpu, If you have access for jenkins server, you can do it under 'Manage Jenkins' section. This would be your path   -- Jenkins Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment Variables -> Add . Then you can add JAVA_HOME values in that section. Name = JAVA_HOME, Value = <path of java home>. Reference : - https://phoenixnap.com/kb/jenkins-environment-variables

Comment: @RajeshGandhavarapu If my answer helped you to get it working, please accept the answer